# unable to show icon using <use> tag in html

Tags: html, css

I came upon the `<use></use>` tag is source code..

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-ghost"></use>
```

I couldn't find much about it. what it is and how is it used?

Sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably referring to the [SVG `<use>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement).

> The ‘use’ element references another element and indicates that the
>   graphical contents of that element is included/drawn at that given
>   point in the document.

Is it inside an `<svg>` element?

Comment: Yes absolutely... Thank you so much.. I was trying to find that documentation